# Bash and PHP - Call functions/commands after a certain amount of time

Tags: php, linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I am very new to PHP and Bash programming and I have some 'basic' questions to ask.

I have created a server using a Raspberry Pi with a PHP scrip which accepts some variables and executes some bash scripts.

That works fine. However, I wanted to add a timer, letting the user to put a certain amount of time in minutes or seconds, or a specific time.

I thought of using the 'cron job', which I'm not familiar with.

What would be your approach? Implementing it in PHP or in Bash and with which function (cron job, some sleep in bash...).

Thank you very much!!

Comment: it's very hard to say without info regarding what your server does. But cron is for regular repeatable jobs, if it's not your case you don't need cron. sleep usually used when you want to delay job starting. If you need to execute a command on some user specified time look at "at" command

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the frequency with which the jobs need to be run, how much jitter (e.g. must the job run at 02:00:00 or is 02:00:10 OK). Using cron should have less of a memory footprint than  a PHP script - and you don't need to worry about memory leaks and the complications o running the PHP as a daemon. OTOH using a PHP script allows for much finer control over when scripts run.

> I am very new to PHP and Bash programming

If this is not something you're familiar with and you want to impement the triggering of other processes, then do have a look at the sleep() function in PHP and the corresponding sleep command available from bash.

Answer (score 0):

Install PHP Cli... and call it from cron:

```
apt-get install php5-cli
```

and maps at cron the call

```
crontab -e
```

and then

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/myPage.php
```

for example, to run every hour.